# Dislocker Error during reading the volume: not enough byte read

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bitlocker

I am using Linux 5.4.0-96-generic #109-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 16:49:16 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
and I have a problem unlocking a NTFS or exFAT volume with bitlocker.

I can mount partitions in the same drive that are not protected with Bitlocker, which leads me to believe that the error I am getting is not a hardware error.

Disk /dev/sdb: 6.101 TiB, 7681501126656 bytes, 15002931888 sectors

Disk model: Micron_5300_MTFD

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disklabel type: gpt

Disk identifier: CAAEB273-5271-45DE-938A-E459A11D17C9

Device Start End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdb1 34 32767 32734 16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2 32768 15002929151 15002896384 7T Microsoft basic data

The commands I have tried are the following which all failed with the same error.

1. `sudo dislocker -v -V /dev/sdb2 -uMyPassword –- /media/bitlocker`
2. `sudo dislocker -v -V /dev/sdb2 -pMyPassword –- /media/bitlocker`
3. `sudo dislocker -v -V /dev/sdb2 -uTheNumbericPassword –-/media/bitlocker`
4. `sudo dislocker -v -V /dev/sdb2 -pTheNumbericPassword –- /media/bitlocker`

Fri Jan 21 15:21:52 2022 [ERROR] Failed to read in #3: Input/output error

Fri Jan 21 15:21:52 2022 [CRITICAL] Error during reading the volume: not enough byte read.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you